# jQuery search word and highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I don't seem to find the problem here. 
My first problem is that I want to highlight several terms in a text.

The second is that my terms are words that contains the same characters as other terms.
Example: direct, indirect.

```
var src_str = $("#test").html();
var term = ["mY text", "needs"];
for (var q=0;q<term.length;q++;) {
    term[q] = term[q].replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
    var pattern = new RegExp("("+term[q]+")", "gi");
    src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
    src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/,"$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");
}

$("#test").html(src_str);
```